# How to generate thumbnail for attachment uploaded via the confluence rest API

Tags: html, python-3.x, confluence-rest-api

I am creating a tool for our own confluence server using python 3.7.3 that uploads attachments to correct pages. What I'd like to do is create a thumbnail from the uploaded documents to the pages. I am using [atlassian-rest-api](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/) to upload documents and update the pages.

How the manually inserted document looks like on page

[image: Example from thumbnail of document]

How the document is opened when clicked

[image]

I am already able to upload attachments and I copied the HTML generated by the confluence to "copy" the structure for inserted attachment. After I upload the document I generate new HTML with the attachment such as this :

```html
    <span class="confluence-embedded-file-wrapper conf-macro output-inline has-comment-overlay" data-hasbody="false" data-macro-name="view-file">
        <a class="confluence-embedded-file" href="/download/attachments/{page_id}/{filename}?version={file_version}&amp;modificationDate={file_mod_date}&amp;api=v2" data-nice-type="text.plain" data-file-src="/download/attachments/{page_id}/{filename}?version={file_version}&amp;modificationDate={file_mod_date}&amp;api=v2" data-linked-resource-id="{file_id}" data-linked-resource-type="attachment" data-linked-resource-container-id="{page_id}" data-linked-resource-default-alias="{filename}" data-mime-type="application/msword" data-has-thumbnail="true" data-linked-resource-version="{file_version}">
            <img src="/rest/documentConversion/latest/conversion/thumbnail/{file_id}/{file_version}" height="250" width="180">
        </a>
        <span class="overlay">
            <span class="file-type-desc-overlay">
                <i class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-file-doc"></i>
                <span class="content">Document</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

This is copied from the HTML of the manually inserted document, but the difference is that the links seems *broken* even thought manually clicking the source actually downloads the file. Also the thumbnail picture seems to be missing because of some automatic conversion process that is taking place when inserting the document into page.

This is how my attempts looks like

[image: Example from thumbnail using the API my way]

When clicking the document

[image]

Do you have any idea how the thumbnails should be handled on page for Confluence API?

edit: It would also seem that during update the site drops part of the attributes added?

[image]

versus when checking the data just before sending it to the API

```html
    <span class="confluence-embedded-file-wrapper conf-macro output-inline has-comment-overlay" data-hasbody="false" data-macro-name="view-file">
        <a class="confluence-embedded-file" data-file-src="/download/attachments/66527941/API test page document.txt?version=50&amp;modificationDate=2020-07-07T15:03:36.916+03:00&amp;api=v2" data-has-thumbnail="true" data-linked-resource-container-id="66527941" data-linked-resource-default-alias="API test page document.txt" data-linked-resource-id="66528088" data-linked-resource-type="attachment" data-linked-resource-version="50" data-mime-type="application/msword" data-nice-type="text.plain" href="/download/attachments/66527941/API test page document.txt?version=50&amp;modificationDate=2020-07-07T15:03:36.916+03:00&amp;api=v2">
            <img height="250" src="/rest/documentConversion/latest/conversion/thumbnail/66528088/50" width="180"/>
        </a>
        <span class="overlay">
            <span class="file-type-desc-overlay">
                <i class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-file-doc"></i>
                <span class="content">Document</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

Edit:

According to [this article](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Confluence-4-0-HTML-element-data/qaq-p/470338) part of the attributes that are not "white listed" are being removed by the APIs parser. This means that we can not manually update the page with elements that have custom defined attributes (such as the data-# which are used by the confluence elements).

Edit 2:

Upon further investigation the missing attributes are probably caused by the [storage format](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html). Using this information I was able to construct similar thumbnail with the following template:

```html
<ac:link ac:anchor="anchor">
  <ri:attachment ri:filename="API test page document.txt"></ri:attachment>
  <ac:link-body>
    <ac:image ac:height="250" ac:width="250" ac:border="true" ac:class="confluence-embedded-file">
      <ri:url ri:value="/plugins/servlet/view-file-macro/placeholder?type=unknown&name=API test page document.txt&attachmentId={attachment id}&version={attachment version}&mimeType=application/binary&height=250"></ri:url>
    </ac:image>
  </ac:link-body>
</ac:link>
```

This produced the following result:

[image: Template result]

Also when clicked it had similar interaction as the one made with editor:

[image: Opened result]

How ever this is still not the result as you get when using the insert with editor.

**Note.** If you use this method, the thumbnail link seems to break if you update anything on the page manually using the editor.

Edit 3: The thumbnail seemed to get broken during editing because of relative URL. Switch the `<ri/url ri:value="/plugins/servlet/...">` to `<ri:url ri:value="https://your.wiki.address/plugins/servlet/...">` and it will no longer break

Comment: can you share your api call? also there's a python library for confluence. https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html#page-actions. much easier to use.

Comment: @user2058738 I am actually using the library that you are referring to. I call the update_page or create_page based on if the page already exists. I append to the existing content if it exists otherwise I create a template page.

Comment: good to hear. I did same with you. I upload file to my confluence page using confluence.attach_file api. then use this to display it as thumbnail.

<ac:structured-macro ac:name="view-file" ac:schema-version="1">
<ac:parameter ac:name="name">
<ri:attachment ri:filename="TEST_FILE.pdf" />
</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="height">500</ac:parameter>
</ac:structured-macro>

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by changing the html implementation to  implementation as I have described in Edit 2 and the secondary issue with the link getting broken is to use absolute URL as said in Edit 3.